# Splitting disk writes between two filesystems based on file extension

Tags: linux, filesystems, performance, overlayfs

#### Background

I am running a proprietary video & audio management application. It reads & writes large multimedia files but also uses a home-grown "database" for metadata. The database consists of multiple millions of small files, spread through hundreds of thousands deeply-nested directories.

#### Problem

The performance of the application is acceptable on fast SSDs. However, with the sheer amount of media files it becomes impractical to store everything on SSDs, where only the metadata (<0.2% of the data) benefits from it.

#### Possible solution?

- Read performance can be solved with [OverlayFs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.5/filesystems/overlayfs.html) combining `/mnt/ssd` & `/mnt/hdd`.
- However, **is there any way to redirect create/write operations on `*.mmd` files to `/mnt/ssd`, while all other falling into `/mnt/hdd`**?

Comment: You want to use [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083624)
to hijack open() calls, rather than malloc() calls, and inject your own logic. You might find it convenient to create symlinks from /mnt/ssd
pointing over to /mnt/hdd.